# Isometric tile map node doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

Isometric tile map node won't appear when I run the product.

```
import SpriteKit    
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {        
  var IsoTileNode = SKSpriteNode () 

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {    
    IsoTileNode = self.childNode(withName: "IsoTileNode") as! SKSpriteNode
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent added it as child to the scene, do self.addChild(IsoTileNode)